# Generating Boostrap 4 nav from json data in react

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I want to create a multi level bootstrap 4 nav using json data in a ReactJS application.
I have a data source providing the menu structure as shown below:

```
[
    {
        "name": "News",
        "url": "/news"
    },
    {.
        "name": "Events",
        "url": "/events"
    },
    {
        "name": "Get Involved",
        "url": "/get-involved",
        "child": [
            {
                "name": "Event Info",
                "url": "/event-info",
                "child": [
                    {
                        "name": "Forms & Resources",
                        "url": "/forms-resources"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Membership",
        "url": "/membership"
    },
    {
        "name": "About",
        "url": "/about"
    }
]
```

I need to convert this into a multi layer bootstrap 4 nav like this:

```
      <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="/news"> News </a> </li>
      <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="/events"> Events </a></li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="/get-involved"> Get Involved </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> Second level 1 </a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/event-info"> Event Info </a>
            <ul class="submenu dropdown-menu">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/forms-resources"> Forms & Resources</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="/membership"> Membership </a> </li>
      <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="/about"> About </a></li>
```

This is for an application I am building in ReactJS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function makeNavItems(items, dropdown = false) {
    return items.map(({ name, url, child }) => {
        const liClass = dropdown ? 'dropdown-item' : 'nav-item'

        return (
            <li class={child ? `${liClass} dropdown` : liClass}>
                <a class={child ? 'nav-link dropdown-toggle' : 'nav-link'} href={url}>{name}</a>
                { child && (
                    <ul className="dropdown-menu">
                        { makeNavItems(child, true)}
                    </ul>
                )}
            </li>
        )
    })
}
```

This should do it for you except for the 'submenu' class on the doubly nested dropdown `ul`... You could try targetting that ul if you need to style it using a nested CSS statement like

```
.dropdown-menu .dropdown-menu {
    // css here
}
```

usage

```
const navItems = makeNavItems(navData)
render(
  <>
    {navItems}
  </>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way, this is not a working code but it will help you guide you to the finish.

If you are using Reactjs Class Components, you can have a state property which will hold all the info regarding your navigation bar.

So lets say your state property is the list that you provided above.

```
let state = {
    navigationBar : [...Contents of the array...]
}
```

After that, in render function, you should have something like this :

```
render(){
          let navbar = "<ul>";// opening ul tag, which will hold our navigation bar

          this.state.navigationBar.forEach(function(el) {

          //This is where you will fill the navbar variable to have content from the array

          navbar +="<li class='nav-item'> <a class='nav-link' href={el.url}>{el.name}</a> </li>";
         });

          navbar += "</ul>"; //closing ul tag

          return ({navbar});
        }
```

Inside foreach loop you should make nested levels for your elements, but this is just a demo to show you the approach I would take. Good Luck ! :)

Answer (score 0):

you need to loop if child array has length.

```js
import React from "react";
import "./style.css";
const list = (data) => {
  return (
    data.map(item => {
      return ( <
        li className = {
          `nav-item ${item.child && item.child.length ? 'dropdown' : ''}`
        } >
        <
        a className = {
          `nav-link ${item.child && item.child.length ? 'dropdown-toggle' : ''
             }`
        }
        href = {
          item.url
        } > {
          item.name
        } <
        /a> {
          item.child && item.child.length &&
            <
            ul className = "dropdown-menu" > {
              item.child.map(ch => < li > < a href = {
                  ch.url
                }
                className = "dropdown-item" > {
                  ch.name
                } < /a> </li > )
            } <
            /ul>
        } <
        /li>
      )
    })
  )
}
export default function App() {
  const data = [{
      "name": "News",
      "url": "/news"
    },
    {
      "name": "Events",
      "url": "/events"
    },
    {
      "name": "Get Involved",
      "url": "/get-involved",
      "child": [{
        "name": "Event Info",
        "url": "/event-info",
        "child": [{
          "name": "Forms & Resources",
          "url": "/forms-resources"
        }]
      }]
    },
    {
      "name": "Membership",
      "url": "/membership"
    },
    {
      "name": "About",
      "url": "/about"
    }
  ]
  return ( <
    div > < ul className = "nav nav-bar" > {
      list(data)
    } <
    /ul> <
    /div>
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Unable to run snippet. I tried on my local host and this only goes 1 level deep. The menu item `Forms & Resources` is missing.